# How to modify the "Add..." string in R shiny selectizeInput with Create =TRUE option?

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

In the R shiny ui, `selectizeInput` allows users to select one element from a list (e.g. "A","B","C" in the example below). With the further option `options=list(create=TRUE)`, users can then also add an item that is not in the provided list. Suppose you want to add "D", the code below works fine and you can easily enter "D" in the box after removing the first proposal (first element of list, i.e. "A"). However, for a non-English-speaking audience, the "Add..." string that comes ahead of the new element as you type in is a little confusing. Is there a way to remove/modify it? I couldn't find this in the options helpers of `selectizeInput`.
Thanks very much for any hint

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(inputId = "ABCother",
                 label="Select or create",
                 choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
                 options=list(create=TRUE))
)

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Update: I can see it comes from the "Add" term within selectize.js (around line 316 as of today)  https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/fc523380c77608383c78e299c8274a83d05ac0a0/src/selectize.js#L316

But if I change selectize.js locally (e.g turning "Add" into "Ajouter"), how can I make sure the shiny app will use the local version (both locally and remotely on shiny io)? Sorry if this is then an entirely different question, then.

Comment: Maybe too awkward: Create forks of the `shiny` package and `selectize.js` on GitHub. Modify `selectize.js` and the [URL](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/60db1e02b03d8e6fb146c9bb1bbfbce269231add/tools/updateSelectize.R#L12) in the `shiny` package, install your new shiny package locally from GitHub with `devtools::install_github()` and deploy. Normally, instead of the CRAN package shiny.io should then use the modified package - j'espère.

Comment: Thanks Peter! Looks a bit heavy procedure (basically for removing 3 letters) but why not indeed. Just had a go but couldn't succeed as yet (https://www.dropbox.com/s/7kunslhouzyuvr0/Screenshot%202021-02-26%20at%2010.44.53.png?dl=0). Must try harder!